# Implementing SAML Identity Provider in Node for Offline app?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

We are in process of building a series of apps that will run offline or in very austere environments.  We'll also be integrating with other 3rd party apps.  Many of these will require logins so we're attempting to use SAML to handle login between them.

I found saml2-js:

https://github.com/Clever/saml2

And it seemed like a great starting point for both the SAML Service Provider and Identity Provider - but diving in I now see it does not implement the Identity Provider at all.

I already have a basic SAML Service Provider setup, but we need an Identity Provider that can run offline.  Are there any Node or GoLang Identity Provider libraries we can use to implement this?  If not, another recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Passport is the usual Node option but that's client side only.

There are a number of IDP's you can use e.g.:

**Free**: simpleSAMLphp / Shibboleth / identityserver4

**Cloud**: Auth0 / Okta / Azure AD

**On-premises**: ADFS